# jQuery $.ajax post method not sending email in joomla

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email, joomla

after going through hundreds of questions, none of the solutions offered have solved my problem. My issue is simple, I have a Joomla module for sending emails. While creating the module on a live server with joomla 3.5.1, all was well but when I installed in another live joomla website in a different server, it does not end any email. Whats weird is that the all other functions in the script works well apart from `$.ajax({` which is essentially responsible for sending data to the server. I had initially thought the error was occurring in the server side but upon sending the email without jQuery, everything works perfectly. My code is as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#dock_send').click(function (e) {
            //First we do some validation,  
            $("#dock_sending").removeClass("hide");

            alerts = '';
            if ($("input[name=dock_skibzy_names]").val() == '') {
                alerts += "1";
                $("#dock_error_name").addClass("error");
            }
            if ($("input[name=dock_skibzy_email]").val() == '') {
                alerts += "1";
                $("#dock_error_email").addClass("error");
            }
            if (!validateEmail($("input[name=dock_skibzy_email]").val())) {
                alerts += "1";
                $("#dock_error_email").addClass("error");
            }
            if ($("input[name=dock_skibzy_phone]").val() == '') {
                alerts += "1";
                $("#dock_error_phone").addClass("error");
            }
            if (!validateNumber($("input[name=dock_skibzy_phone]").val())) {
                alerts += "1";
                $("#dock_error_phone").addClass("error");
            }
            if ($("input[name=dock_skibzy_subj]").val() == '') {
                alerts += "1";
                $("#dock_error_subj").addClass("error");
            }
            if ($("select[name=dock_skibzy_subj_cat]").val() == '' && $("input[name=dock_cat_vis]").val() == 'yes') {
                alerts += "1";
                $("#dock_error_subj_cat").addClass("error");
            }
            if ($("textarea[name=dock_skibzy_msg]").val() == '') {
                alerts += "1";
                $("#dock_error_msg").addClass("error");
            }
            if ($("textarea[name=dock_skibzy_msg]").val().length < 10) {
                alerts += "1";
                $("#dock_error_msg").addClass("error");
            }

            if (alerts != '') {
                $("#dock_sending").addClass("hide");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                    data: $("#dock_skibzy_form").serialize(),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        show_ok();
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $("#msg_not_sent").removeClass("hide");
                        $("#dock_sending").addClass("hide");
                    }
                });
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $("#dock_skibzy_names").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#dock_error_name").removeClass("error");
        });

        $("#dock_skibzy_email").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#dock_error_email").removeClass("error");
        });

        $("#dock_skibzy_phone").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#dock_error_phone").removeClass("error");
        });

        $("#dock_skibzy_subj").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#dock_error_subj").removeClass("error");
        });

        $("#dock_skibzy_subj_cat").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#dock_error_subj_cat").removeClass("error");
        });

        $("#dock_skibzy_msg").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#dock_error_msg").removeClass("error");
        });

        $("#msg_sent").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#dock_msg_sent").addClass("hide");
            $("#dock_sending").addClass("hide");
        });

        function show_ok() {
            $("#dock_sending").addClass("hide");
            $("#dock_msg_sent").removeClass("hide");

            $("input").val('');
            $("select").val('');
            $("textarea").val('');
        }

        function validateEmail($email) {
            var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
            return emailReg.test($email);
        }

        function validateNumber($num) {
            var intReg = /^\d+$/;
            return intReg.test($num);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You are using `POST` in you ajax request but provide query string, which is commonly used with `GET`. Try to use `GET` instead of  `POST`. But if you still want to pass string try to add `object` in your `data` field : `data: {query:$("#dock_skibzy_form").serialize() }`

Comment: That has not worked. What I do not understand is why it stopped working in he new server. I have the same code on another joomla website and it works perfectly